# I want to center my grid item to be centered in HTML and CSS template

Tags: html, css

The current situation is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aERl3.png)

I want this Product to be in center. the code for this is:

```html
<div class="row isotope-grid">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="images/product-01.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="product-detail.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    Esprit Ruffle Shirt
                                </a>

                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    $16.64
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out as i am a learner and new to this thing.

Comment: the picture link looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: Pretty sure this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element/114549#114549

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:100vh;}

img{
max-width:500px;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div class="row isotope-grid">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="product-detail.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    Esprit Ruffle Shirt
                                </a>

                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    $16.64
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: This helped me to center the grid but now the picture isn't vissible.

Comment: which image isn't loading or can't be seen?

Comment: snippet updated.  try adding a max-width:500px to your images

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css to center things

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

to center vertically and horizontally

```
    div.container4 {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative }
div.container4 p {
    margin: 0;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
```

to center text

```
text-align: center;
```

in your case

```css
.block2{
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="row isotope-grid">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <!-- Block2 -->
                    <div class="block2">
                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="images/product-01.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                            <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                                Quick View
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="product-detail.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    Esprit Ruffle Shirt
                                </a>

                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    $16.64
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                    <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                    <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

You can control of the top if you don't want it to be at the middle top: 20%;